# Why counter resets when I click on other link?

Tags: php, pagination

I have define a `counter` in `while loop` and it is initialized outside the loop.

I have `echo` the counter in `loop` itself. When I have 50 record on first page it displays 1 to 25. The problem is that on second page it start again from 1, not like it should work: to start it from 26 to 50.

Here is my code:

```
        <?php
        //show records
        $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT table2.col2 AS a,table1.col2 AS   b, table1.col1 AS c, table1.q_url AS d FROM {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} ,   {$limit}");
        $Authorname='';
        $count=1;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {


        $output='';
        $Authorname =$row['a'];
          $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
          $url=explode('/',$url);
          ?>
        <div class="record round"><?php echo  $count;$output .='<a     href="http://localhost/quotes/'.$url[5].'/'.$row['d'].'.html">';
         echo $output .=$row['b'].'</a>';?></div>
          <?php 
          $count++; 

        }
        ?>
```

Comment: You are not persisting the count. You set $count=1; but no-where is this saved. Save it to the DB for this record?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
Try

```
$nbpage = 2;
$nbresultperpage=25;

$count = ($nbpage-1)*$nbresultperpage;
```

Where `$nbpage` is you're current number of page